# Unknown value 'f' for boolean field 'Use Company Address', assuming 'yes' at row 2

Tags: csv, openerp-7

I have a combine a csv file of both `res_users` and `res_partner` tables and I import it to the openerp application of v7, but I am getting error below:

```
Unknown value 'f' for boolean field 'Use Company Address', assuming 'yes' at row 2
Use '1' for yes and '0' for no
(665 more)
Unknown value 'f' for boolean field 'Opt-Out', assuming 'yes' at row 2
Use '1' for yes and '0' for no
(665 more)
No matching record found for name '235' in field 'Country' at row 2
Get all possible values
(35 more)
No matching record found for name '1' in field 'Company' at row 2
Get all possible values
(665 more)
Unknown value 'f' for boolean field 'Employee', assuming 'yes' at row 2
Use '1' for yes and '0' for no
(665 more)
Unknown value 'f' for boolean field 'Customer', assuming 'yes' at row 2
Use '1' for yes and '0' for no
(665 more)
Unknown value 'f' for boolean field 'Supplier', assuming 'yes' at row 2
Use '1' for yes and '0' for no
(665 more)
Unknown value 't' for boolean field 'Active', assuming 'yes' at row 2
Use '1' for yes and '0' for no
(665 more)
Unknown value 'f' for boolean field 'Is a Company', assuming 'yes' at row 2
Use '1' for yes and '0' for no
(665 more)
No matching record found for name '7' in field 'State' at row 2
Get all possible values
(31 more)
'1/29/2015' does not seem to be a valid date for field 'Latest connection' at row 3
Use the format '2012-12-31'
(3 more)
'2/6/2015' does not seem to be a valid date for field 'Latest connection' at row 9
Use the format '2012-12-31'
'9/9/2014' does not seem to be a valid date for field 'Latest connection' at row 14
Use the format '2012-12-31'
'1/22/2015' does not seem to be a valid date for field 'Latest connection' at row 15
Use the format '2012-12-31'
No matching record found for name '27' in field 'State' at row 26
Get all possible values
(2 more)
No matching record found for name '25' in field 'State' at row 34
Get all possible values
```

How do I resolve it, kindly suggest me.
kindly suggest me, waiting for reply.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In import csv, avoid `'f'` for boolean try with `0 for false` and `1 for true`

And their are many wrong format in your csv as per error suggestion try with that format. Afterwards it will import successfully.

For Example:

1. Date import format:

   Use this format 2012-12-31 instead of 2/6/2015 like 2015-02-06
2. For boolean field:

   0 for False and 1 for True
3. No matching record found for name '27' in field 'State' at row 26
   Get all possible values

   Go to csv file and checkout record row 26 with state field.  That value check in OpenERP whether is correct. If that state is not create than first create state in OpenERP than try to import.